# Segmentation fault on reboot Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, reboot

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 Server image running on a VMWare VM. I am getting a Segmentation Fault when rebooting the system. I am unable to figure out what the problem might be.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, 80 days turn on... what did you expect. BTW, did you make sure that you have all package updated and the Virtual Disk is intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact source of the problem. I had installed linux-3.8 kernel (raring). It must have a problem with ESXi 5. I've moved back to the default kernel (3.5), and the issue doesn't seem to appear.